# ZMQ 4.1.3 basic example running error in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, zeromq

I'm trying to use zmq 4.1.3 in Ubuntu.

I installed zmq by following commands.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure && make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

When I specify the location of installed zmq 4.1.3, I got core dump messages. However, if I dont tell the location of zmq, it works well.

In sum,

```
examples works well with zmq in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
libzmq.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.1 (0x00007f58e4ff9000)
```

examples do not work with zmq in /usr/local/lib (newly installed directory)

```
root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# g++ hwserver.cpp -o main -lzmq -L/usr/local/lib

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# g++ hwclient.cpp -o main2 -lzmq -L/usr/local/lib

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# ./main&
[1] 27017

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# ./main2

Connecting to hello world server...
Sending Hello 0...
Received Hello

main: /usr/include/zmq.hpp:131: zmq::message_t::~message_t(): Assertion `rc == 0' failed.

Received World 0

main2: /usr/include/zmq.hpp:131: zmq::message_t::~message_t(): Assertion `rc == 0' failed.

Abort (core dumped)

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# g++ hwclient.cpp -o main2 -lzmq
[1]+  Abort               (core dumped) ./main

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# g++ hwclient.cpp -o main2 -lzmq

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# g++ hwserver.cpp -o main -lzmq

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# ./main&
[1] 27066

root@jangho-Z87M-HD3:/zeromq/zguide/examples/C++# ./main2

Connecting to hello world server...
Sending Hello 0...
Received Hello
Received World 0
Sending Hello 1...
```

Comment: Possibly you are using `zmq.h` from one version of libzmq and linking with another.